# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '______')

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Anything that I change to make this code work just changes said undefined thing.
I have tried to fix using multiple different answers, but no luck.

```js
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, message } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');
const guildId = '1009548907015057460';
const channelId = '1009548907702915245';

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    const { commandName } = interaction;

    if (commandName === 'invite') {
        const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(guildId);
        console.log(guild);
        const channel = await guild.channels.cache.get(channelId);
        let invite = await guild.channel.createInvite(
            {
                maxAge: 300000,
                maxUses: 1,
            },
            '${message.author.tag} requested a invite',
        ).catch(console.log);
        await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });
        await interaction.editReply(invite ? 'Join: ${invite}' : 'Error');
    }
}
```

Anything can help.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to fetch the guild, you can get the channel from the client
- There's no need for `await` when you're getting information from cache
- `guild.channel.createInvite` should be `channel.createInvite`
- You're using single quotes for variables, they'll end up being strings
- There's no need for `invite` to use `let` when the value doesn't change
- Defer the reply at the beginning rather than right before replying
- `message.author.tag` would return undefined, `message` doesn't exist. Use `interaction.user.tag` instead
- Add `await` to `channel.createInvite` as it returns a promise
- Replace `${invite}` with `${invite.url}`

Also it's best to store the token in a `.env` file rather than a JSON one.

```js
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, message } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const channelId = '1009548907702915245';

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
    await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });

    const { commandName } = interaction;

    if (commandName === 'invite') {
        const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelId);

        const invite = await channel.createInvite({
            maxAge: 604800, // 1 week
            maxUses: 1,
            reason: `${interaction.user.tag} requested an invite`
        }).catch(console.log);
        
        interaction.editReply(invite ? `Join: ${invite.url}` : 'Error');
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try this, my bot says this: "Join: [object Promise]" Any fixes?

Comment: @z_aa Try `Join: ${invite.url}` (or `invite.code` if you just want the code) and add `await` to `channel.createInvite` since it returns a promise.

Comment: I resolved the promise. That seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Resolving the promise works. This is the code after:

```js
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, message } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const channelId = '1009548907702915245';

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
    await interaction.deferReply({ ephemeral: true });

    const { commandName } = interaction;

    if (commandName === 'invite') {
        const channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelId);

        const invite = channel.createInvite({
            maxAge: 604800, // 1 week
            maxUses: 1,
            reason: `${interaction.user.tag} requested an invite`
        })
        .catch(console.log);
        const promise = Promise.resolve(invite);

        promise.then((value) => {
            interaction.editReply(`Join: ${value}`);
        });
        
        
    }
}
```